# Robot Framework and Python: Run Keyword and continue without it finishing

Tags: python, robotframework

I'd like to do something like this in Robot:

```
Start process1
Run keyword1
Run keyword2
Stop process1 #Using kill -9
```

So, I need my python keyword to create a subprocess and have that process run in the background. I also need robot to be able to continue to Run keyword1 without process1 ever completing. Is this something that threading would be used for, or should I use subprocesses? How would I go about this?

Comment: `start process` is documented to run the process in the background. Is that not happening for you?

Comment: @BryanOakley The process I'd like to start is my own keyword. I see the documentation for `start process` takes a command line argument. Could I just make my keyword an executable and just have `start process` with it?

Comment: So, you don't want to run a _process_, you want to run a _keyword_ as if it were a separate process?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, exactly.

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#parallel-execution-of-keywords